# SQL Server data not being shown while executing with stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pa_AnadeCine3]
    @Nombre AS      VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Empresa AS     VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @CIF AS         VARCHAR(12) = '',
    @Direccion AS   VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Localidad AS   VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Provincia AS   VARCHAR(20) = '',
    @CP AS          VARCHAR(5) = '',
    @Tlf1 AS        VARCHAR(12) = '',
    @NumeroSalas AS SMALLINT = 0,
    @Metro AS       VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Bus AS         VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Email AS       VARCHAR(100) = '',
    @GPS AS         VARCHAR(100) = ''
AS
    DECLARE @Fecha AS VARCHAR(23)
    DECLARE @Error AS INT

    SET @Fecha = CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 121)

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO dbo.SiveCines (Nombre, Empresa, CIF, Direccion, Localidad, Provincia, CP, Tlf1, NumeroSalas, Metro, Bus, Email, GPS, FechaActualizacion)
        VALUES (@Nombre, @Empresa, @CIF, @Direccion, @Localidad, @Provincia, @CP, @Tlf1, @NumeroSalas, @Metro, @Bus, @Email, @GPS, @Fecha)

        SELECT
            @@ERROR    AS N'Error',
            @@ROWCOUNT AS N'Fila',
            @@IDENTITY as N'ID_Cine'

      /* CONTROL DE ERRORES. */
      IF @Error = 0
      BEGIN
          COMMIT TRANSACTION
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
      END
```

The problem is when I execute this stored procedure, no error occurs, and a new `cine_id` is returned for example 2. But the data doesn't show up in the database when I do `select * from sivecines where sivecines.ID_Cine=2` and the data is also not inserted when I view all the data. But when I insert the new data manually then `Id_cine` of 2 is escaped and new Id_cine will become 3. I don't know where the data with ID_Cine=2 went.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: You never set `@Error`, so you wouldn't know if an error occurred and (because it defaults to 0) would always commit the transaction, even if you shouldn't.

Comment: also, don't use @@IDENTITY.....

Comment: What should I use instead of identity

Comment: @ashokpoudel You don't need a transaction for a singel INSERT statement, they are atomic. If you want to do something if an error occurs, use [TRY CATCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Again, you don't need it for single INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements

Comment: @ashokpoudel to return the newly inserted values use the [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  of INSERT/UPDATE, eg `INSERT .. OUTPUT inserted.ID`

Comment: `SET @Fecha = CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 121)` that's a HUGE bug. *Never* store dates as strings. Use the `date` type. Otherwise you'll *definitely* mix up the formats at some point

Comment: I know but thats my client requirement

Comment: @ashokpoudel no it's not. Did they specifically ask you in writing to store February 31st dates? No way. They may have asked you to *display* the dates in a certain way in the **client** application but **never** to store bad data. They may have asked that dates are **displayed** in a certain format. Date types have no format. The *client* converts them to strings and displays them in a certain way

Comment: The store procedure was given by my client when I personally use the database I always use datetime and I also don't use store procedure for atomic statement also

Comment: @ashokpoudel if the client asked you to clean up their code, you have one more thing to charge them for then

Comment: Haha . Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you'll never commit the transaction as you are not setting @Error

you declare it then use:

```
  IF @Error = 0
    BEGIN
      COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END
```

Declaring a variable and not declaring it defaults to `NULL`:

```
DECLARE @Error INT
SELECT @Error
```

Would return `NULL`

`NULL` <> 0 :

```
IF 0 = NULL
    BEGIN
        PRINT 1;
END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 2;
END;
```

Returns `2`

Check to see if there are any open transactions when you run the proc or add a `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint when you query the table to see if the data is there